# JQuery me cambia el style sólo una vez. Quiero que lo haga más veces

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buenas y gracias de ante mano.

Tengo un documento que añade card cada vez que pulsas un botón.

Cada card contiene un  que envuelve a una

Html:

```
<div id="xxx"><table></table></div>
```

Usando JQuery, quiero que este div que envuelve la table tenga un borde sólido a cada card que se vaya añadiendo.

Función JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(probando());

function probando(){
if(unidades != null){ //aquí siempre me da bien las unidades porque saco un alert que me lo 
indica
$("#xxx").css('border', '1px solid black');
}
}
```

El problema es que me funciona solo la primera vez. El resto de veces, aunque siga habiendo unidades que entren en el if, no me vuelve a pintar los bordes en las siguientes card que se van añadiento, sólo en la primera.

Espero que me podáis ayudar. Gracias

Comment: Debes evitar tener un mismo ID usado para múltiples elementos dentro de tu DOM. El ID es un identificador único, si lo tienes repetido provocas este tipo de comportamientos. Plantéate usar una clase en vez de un ID: `<div class="xxx"><table></table></div>`

Comment: ese id es único sólo para ese div. Es una card que se va añadiendo pero el div es siempre el mismo

Comment: @phpMyGuel tenías razón, ha funcionado con una clase en vez de con el id. Muchas gracias. Saludos